# VBA code mod to copy 4 ranges on a sheet to summary sheets

Tags: excel

Hi im looking for a code like this but i need to set a range say B4 to M35 to be copied to a sheet which will then drive a pivot table, also i find this code keeps over-writting the previous copied data so i need this to find empty rows to paste to.
so on say a sheet named day1 i will need by means of adding macro to a button for each range to copy a range from B4 to J35. to a summary.
Then again on another seperate summary sheet i would need say range B40 to M70.
Then again B75 to M105 to another sheet
and B110 to M140 to another sheet.

Then i need to copy the same code to other sheets day2 , day3 , day4

at the end of the 4 days i would then have 4 summary sheets from the four ranges from each sheet to then drive a pivot table from each summary sheet which will be increased each time a range is saved each day.

```
Sub CopyRows1()
Dim bottomL As Integer
Dim x As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("day1").Range("A" & ROWS.Count).End(XLUP).Row: x = 1

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("day1").Range("A4:A" & bottomL)
    If c.Value >= "" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little confusing, but I think you are saying that for each day you will have multiple buttons. Each one will be assigned a section from that day and will write that section into a separate summary sheet?

Try this, it would involve setting up a separate macro for each button that designate the range you want to copy and which summary sheet you want it to go to:

```
Sub ButtonDay1()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim ThisDayRange As Range

    Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
    'Set this to the range you want to move to a summary sheet
    Set ThisDayRange = wsSource.Range("B4:M35")

    'Call the AddToSummary function to send to the desired sheet
    AddToSummary ThisDayRange, Sheets("Summary1")

End Sub
```

Then call this function to write it:

```
Function AddToSummary(DayRange As Range, SummarySheet As Worksheet)
    Dim AddRow As Integer
    Dim Item As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    AddRow = SummarySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If AddRow <> 1 Then
        AddRow = AddRow + 1
    End If

    For i = 1 To DayRange.Rows.Count
        If DayRange.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            For b = 1 To DayRange.Columns.Count
                SummarySheet.Cells(AddRow, b).Value = DayRange.Cells(i, b).Value
            Next b

            AddRow = AddRow + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

If you wanted to just re-use the same macro for each button you could write an input box that asks for the range and summary sheet values

Comment: Yes you have got it spot on Thank you.

Comment: is there a way in which the first part can look in column B for any value of text within the range of cells and only copy those rows over using this code you have done which is working fine.

Comment: So just to clarify, within the given range you want to check Column B and if it has text then copy that row? If it doesn't have text will it be blank or have a number?

Comment: Yes it would be someones name in column B but the range B4:M35 would rarely be filled all the way, the same for the other group of ranges and names, if the cell in B is empty then there would be no further data in that row so it would not need to be copied.  Hope that makes sense, thank you for taking the time out on this.

Comment: I updated the AddToSummary Function, mark the answer correct if that works for you.

Comment: wow!  That is perfection in motion, cant thank you enough for your time , many thanks